# SimpleXMLElement file does not load xmlString

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to work on an XML Based problem. So far, it's proving to be a bummer for some reason. My code is only two lines and for some reason nothing is loading in.

The code:

```
$xmlString = file_get_contents('file.xml');
$xmlObject = simplexml_load_string($xmlString); 
// also in the above line I have tried
// 1. new SimpleXMLElement('file.xml') 
// 2. simplexml_load_file('file.xml')
```

The functions do not load, and this I can tell by var_dumping $xmlObject, which returns 
boolean false.

file_get_contents does load the string $xmlString and var_dumping it returns the string, so location of the file path is not an issue here.

Anybody know what's happening here?

Thanks

Comment: Is `file.xml`'s content valid? The function need a well-formed XML string.

Comment: Sharing the content of file.xml will be helpful.
Also see how to deal with xml errors http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php

Comment: how can I validate if this is a valid xml file?

Comment: You can use a service like http://www.xmlvalidation.com/ Or any other service you will find when googling "xml validation"

Comment: gotcha, I was able to find out why this was wrong, downloaded the source again and the previous version of file.xml was for some reason missing a tag...probably because of me...thanks for sourcing me to xmlvalidation

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is probably invalid. Look at the fine PHP manual that describes how to handle those errors:

http://php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-errors.php

You can also validate your XML with command line tools like xmllint:

```
$ xmllint --noout /path/to/file.xml
file.xml:1: parser error : XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document
```